# How do I enable languages for the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: symfony1

My application uses the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin to secure the application and force uses to login to access.  How do I enable the i18n features in Symfony so that users can get different language when they login?

As per the Symfony Internationalization document I added the following to my settings.yml:

all:
  .settings:
    charset: utf-8
    i18n: true
    standard_helpers: [Partial, Cache, I18N]

and the following routes to my routing.yml:

But when I got to /fr/ all is still stubbornly in English.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you did to enable i18n seems to be sufficient.

Did you translate the messages? Translations are not included in the plugin.

Comment: No, I didn't add my own translations.  There is an i18n directory with translation files for fr and es within the plugin directory, so I assume it would use those.  Do you know what those files are there for?

/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/i18n/sf_guard.fr.xml
/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/i18n/sf_guard.es.xml

Comment: You're right. Translations are there and you should get the pages translated. Could you paste your route? It's truncated from the question.